# How to get ip address of PC on which installed personal bitbucket server with repository?

Tags: git, ssh, ip, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I have a java project on Bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/myProjectName/myRepositoryName/src/master/

This is links to clone my project:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:myProjectName/MyRepositoryName.git
git clone https://userName@bitbucket.org/myProjectName/MyRepositoryName.git
```

It is located somewhere on our company server. But somehow people forgot where it is located (on which physical machine). And I need to know somehow what is IP address of this server. I searched everywhere in settings, but I didn't find anything. All commands that I have used - they only show the SSH path to your repository (not actual IP address). I have even installed Bitbucket Server on my own PC to make everything clear for me, but still don't understand. Can anyone help: **How to get ID address of personal bitbucket server?** Thanks.

This is what I see when installing bitbucket server:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

nmap should be able to help you find this server, especially if you used the default ports for things:

`nmap -p 7990 <your local network subnet>`

This will show all IPs on the specified network that have port 7990 open. (Bitbucket Server uses 7990 for HTTP. You can also scan for port 7999, Bitbucket Server's default SSH port.)

Comment: Where I can find "local network subnet"? And where to run command "nmap"? Because when I run in "cmd" console it tells me: "nmap is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file".

Comment: There is no way for anybody on here to know anything about how your network is set up.